# Dynamic residential power system

Tags: relay, watts

I have a farm with solar panels. Right now, it is powering the house, and excess gets sold to the electric company. I was thinking that instead I could have the excess power bitcoin mining equipment. Is there a way to essentially turn off a specific line when the house is drawing over a certain number of watts? I am thinking some sort of relay. I am not an electrical engineer, and this may not be the right place to ask this, but I would appreciate any insight. The actual problem is more complex than I described, because it also depends on how much is being generated at that moment. But, basically, I want to turn the equipment on when solar power > bitcoin mining power ( a constant value ) + house power.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how things are right now, but I think you will pretty much lose money mining any well-stablished crypto currency.

Second, the proper way to do it would be to have the mining rig know the current solar power and house consumption and properly size how much energy it could use at that time, since turning it on and off might hurt performance or reduce the life of the rig.
Lastly, it might be possible to use the simple approach you suggested, turning the device on/off based on some controller connected to the inverter (since most of them nowadays have apps you should be able to have some "computer" read those info). But that seems flawed, since it would only work for some fixed amount of surplus energy and would probably shutdown the rig all the time unless you have a huge safety margin for the power consumed by the rig.

Comment: Just to your first sentence and not the rest, what the OP receives for energy from the electric company may not be the same as what the OP pays for the same energy. So the calculus may not be so well-determined by outside analysts. But your point remains as a general rule. Just it's uncertain if it applies in this exact case. Only the OP can answer that question and only after some serious thinking about it.

Comment: Yeah the electric company gives a severely reduced rate.  Normally mining isnt profitable where I'm at, but given free energy its always profitable, its just a matter if it makes more than what the electric company gives. Both things id need to look into.  I see your point about the safety margin. Perhaps a battery could be used as a buffer so spikes dont interrupt use, and it will only shut off when there is a long term deficit.